# special case of matrix multiplication

Tags: r, matrix-multiplication

I'm trying to multiply matrices in R but using apply functions. In this particular case, I'm looking to handle NAs, for which I saw nothing in `crossprod` to handle, or with %*%

```
set.seed(3141)
mat1 <- c(1:50)
pos <- sample(c(1:50),14)
mat1[pos] <- NA
mat1 <- matrix(mat1,10,5)
mat2 <- matrix(sample(c(0,1),20,replace=T),5,4)
```

mat1:

```
       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
  [1,]    1   11   NA   31   41
  [2,]   NA   12   NA   32   NA
  [3,]   NA   13   NA   NA   NA
  [4,]    4   14   24   34   44
  [5,]    5   15   25   NA   45
  [6,]    6   16   26   36   46
  [7,]    7   17   27   37   47
  [8,]    8   18   28   NA   NA
  [9,]    9   19   29   NA   49
 [10,]   10   20   NA   40   NA
```

mat2:

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] 
 [1,]    0    0    0    1 
 [2,]    1    0    1    1 
 [3,]    0    1    0    0 
 [4,]    0    1    1    0 
 [5,]    1    1    1    1
```

So mat1 has some NAs thrown in and mat2 is like a punchcard of old, tracking which elements of mat1 to keep in the result (so it's not *complete* multiplication in the truest sense - the punchcard was really what I was after and the multiplication seemed a way to get it). Using %*%,

```
mat3 <- mat1 %*% mat2

      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
 [1,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
 [2,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
 [3,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
 [4,]   58  102   92   62
 [5,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
 [6,]   62  108   98   68
 [7,]   64  111  101   71
 [8,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
 [9,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
[10,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
```

with NAs all over the place. First attempt to deal with them:

```
    mat4 <- t(apply(mat1,1,function(x){apply(mat2,2,function(y){sum(x*y,na.rm=T)})}))

      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
 [1,]   52   72   83   53
 [2,]   12   32   44   12
 [3,]   13    0   13   13
 [4,]   58  102   92   62
 [5,]   60   70   60   65
 [6,]   62  108   98   68
 [7,]   64  111  101   71
 [8,]   18   28   18   26
 [9,]   68   78   68   77
[10,]   20   40   60   30
```

which was better, but the picky complication is that I want to remove any result that tried to include an NA from mat1 so it doesn't contribute to the final.

```
mat5 <- t(apply(mat1,1,function(x){
  apply(mat2,2,function(y){
    ifelse(is.na(sum(x[as.logical(y)])),
           0,
           sum(x*y,na.rm=T))
  })}))

      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
 [1,]   52    0   83   53
 [2,]    0    0    0    0
 [3,]    0    0    0    0
 [4,]   58  102   92   62
 [5,]   60    0    0   65
 [6,]   62  108   98   68
 [7,]   64  111  101   71
 [8,]    0    0    0    0
 [9,]   68    0    0   77
[10,]    0    0    0    0
```

which is where I was headed, in that I only throw out the result if there was an NA from mat1 (ie. mat2 had a corresponding 1, but if not, then the NA is fine).

The question is, is this an efficient solution? Have I missed something in base that would make this go faster? (short of parallelization, as I am sadly on Windows where such a thing is not for the faint of heart). This seems clunky and it will have to be performed several million times across multiple arrays, so any speedup would be useful. Thanks.

**UPDATE:**
thank you to the two responses thus far. I thought I'd run a timing comparison on my machine to see how the methods might differ. Unfortunately I couldn't get the C++ to work. I got an error message that an error occurred building a shared library. It advised downloading a compatible version of Rtools from CRAN (I'm using R3.2.3) which I did, but I'm also thinking of this having to run on other computers (like my boss's) where the need for additional installations and such to get this working may not be ideal. Packages, I can write into code, but visiting a site to download something additional not part of the standard installation if the code throws an error to fix it, a bit more complicated. Anyway, for the others:

```
meth1 <- function(m1,m2){
  t(apply(m1,1,function(x){
    apply(m2,2,function(y){
      ifelse(is.na(sum(x[as.logical(y)])),
             0,
             sum(x*y,na.rm=T))
    })}))
}
meth2 <- function(m1,m2){
  m1[is.na(m1)] <- 10^20
  res <- m1 %*% m2
  res[abs(res) > 10^10] <- 0
  res
}

library(Matrix)
meth4 <- function(m1,m2){
  M1 <- Matrix(m1,sparse=TRUE)
  M2 <- Matrix(m2,sparse=TRUE)
  res <- M1 %*% M2
  res[is.na(res)] <- 0
  Matrix(res,sparse = F)
}

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark({meth1(mat1,mat2)},{meth2(mat1,mat2)},{meth4(mat1,mat2)},times=100)
```

yielding:

```
Unit: microseconds
                      expr      min       lq       mean   median       uq
 {     meth1(mat1, mat2) }  475.957  516.155  563.41297  535.826  568.754
 {     meth2(mat1, mat2) }    8.126    9.836   14.78396   15.609   18.816
 {     meth4(mat1, mat2) } 4535.489 4764.701 5016.47097 4901.331 5008.025
      max neval
 1763.565   100
   30.791   100
 9722.265   100
```

Shame about the Rcpp one - I appreciate that it looks like no small amount of effort and things in C tend to run faster still. That "quick and dirty" kind of won the day by orders of magnitude and only uses base. Thanks for the suggestions (all three)

Comment: The benchmark you did may not really be a fair comparison. for meth4, the function probably only needs a single line "m1 %*% m2". Converting your matrix objects to Matrix will not be required if you create them in the 1st instance using Matrix(), rather than matrix(). similarly converting back to matrix at the end is almost certainly unnecessary. If you are as you say going to be working with very large matrix operations, then sparse matrixes could save a lot of memory.

Comment: ok, fair enough. Not familiar with the package and so wanted minimal disruption to the rest of the code, thinking for example of experiences with how data.table did funny things to data.frame handling. But will look at the package more closely

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick but dirty solution is to replace `NA` with a suffciently high value and then use a threshold to pick out the zeros:

```
mat1[is.na(mat1)] <- 10^200
A <- mat1 %*% mat2
A[abs(A) > 10^100] <- 0
A
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
 [1,]   52    0   83   53
 [2,]    0    0    0    0
 [3,]    0    0    0    0
 [4,]   58  102   92   62
 [5,]   60    0    0   65
 [6,]   62  108   98   68
 [7,]   64  111  101   71
 [8,]    0    0    0    0
 [9,]   68    0    0   77
[10,]    0    0    0    0
```

or you could simply write your own using Rcpp the plain way:

```
library(inline)
library(Rcpp)
cppFunction(
    'NumericMatrix f(NumericMatrix mat1, NumericMatrix mat2) {
        double val;
        NumericMatrix X(mat1.nrow(), mat2.ncol());
        for (int i = 0; i < mat1.nrow(); ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < mat1.ncol(); ++j) {
                val = 0;
                for(int k = 0; k < mat1.ncol(); k++){
                    if(NumericVector::is_na(mat1(i, k))){
                        if( mat2(k, j) != 0) {
                            val = 0;
                            break;
                        }
                    } else val += mat1(i, k)*mat2(k, j);
                }
                X(i, j) = val;
            }
        }
        return X;
    }'
)

> f(mat1, mat2)
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
 [1,]   52    0   83   53
 [2,]    0    0    0    0
 [3,]    0    0    0    0
 [4,]   58  102   92   62
 [5,]   60    0    0   65
 [6,]   62  108   98   68
 [7,]   64  111  101   71
 [8,]    0    0    0    0
 [9,]   68    0    0   77
[10,]    0    0    0    0
```

Comment: Wow, thanks. That's pretty deep there - I will need to look further into this Rcpp of which you write, but even the first seems like it should be a faster solution, obviating the multiple applys and the ifelse check in the middle with each iteration that I had in my method

Answer (score 2):

Simplest approach may be to use sparse matrices.

```
library(Matrix)
M1 <- Matrix(mat1,sparse=TRUE)
M2 <- Matrix(mat2,sparse=TRUE)
ans <- M1 %*% M2
ans
10 x 4 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"

 [1,] 52  NA  83 53
 [2,] NA  NA  NA NA
 [3,] NA  NA  NA NA
 [4,] 58 102  92 62
 [5,] 60  NA  NA 65
 [6,] 62 108  98 68
 [7,] 64 111 101 71
 [8,] NA  NA  NA NA
 [9,] 68  NA  NA 77
[10,] NA  NA  NA NA
```

If you wish, you can replace NA with 0:

```
ans[is.na(ans)] <- 0
Matrix(ans,sparse = F)

 10 x 4 Matrix of class "dgeMatrix"
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
 [1,]   52    0   83   53
 [2,]    0    0    0    0
 [3,]    0    0    0    0
 [4,]   58  102   92   62
 [5,]   60    0    0   65
 [6,]   62  108   98   68
 [7,]   64  111  101   71
 [8,]    0    0    0    0
 [9,]   68    0    0   77
[10,]    0    0    0    0
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Was not aware of this package or sparse matrices. Will check timings.